# Calling back up to a certain line in a certain file, for each buttons in MATLAB gui (guide)

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I recently discovered about MATLAB's builtin guide GUI interface. I wanted to make an app to run some example model codes that I have. I will list them in order below to avoid possible confusion!

1. A button, once pressed, runs up to line 50 in file A, which creates data.
2. This new data displayed to the table.
3. A button that runs up to line 100 in file A, which plots two different graphs.
4. A slider that changes a parameter of the plot function which would then change the shape of the plot.

I'm just really new to using the guide, so I'm kind of lost on how to start, so any help/pointers would be appreciated!!

Also, is MATLAB's guide a popular way of creating apps/interfaces for the code, or is there a better alternative? I kind of find the resources/help guides limited for it.

Comment: MATLAB `GUIDE` is only useful to organise the _layout_ of your GUI instead of having to create and position every GUI element programatically. GUIDE will not help you generate code for anything else. You should be able to create code that does what you want, then you can create the GUI with a button which calls that code.

Comment: "I'm kind of lost on how to start" means that the question is too broad for SO. I recommend you start with reading [the tutorials](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/gui-development.html), try to implement what you're trying to do, and come back here if you get stuck at any specific point. Such specific questions are what SO is about. Nobody is going to write a tutorial here for how to build an app using Guide, and nobody is going to write the app for you either.

Comment: Also, as you see in that link I posted, the App Designer is the recommended way of creating apps in MATLAB. GUIDE is the old way, much more stable, and your apps will run on older versions of MATLAB too. The App Designer is being improved with every release, so what you build will likely not work with a previous version of MATLAB.

Comment: @Hoki yeah, I realized it's useful to use guide for general layout of the structure and set positions, and later make changes with code. Thanks!

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hey thanks for the tutorials link. I will refer to it, and will come back with more specific questions :)